# Direct3D11CaptureFramePool frame is null in async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am trying to use the `Windows.Graphics.Capture` namespace to capture screenshot from a comaptible application.

I based my code on the official examples here: [MS sample screenshot code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture)

The code in question is the following:

```
  private async void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName == "xxxxxxxxxxx").Single();
        hwnd = process.MainWindowHandle;

        GraphicsCaptureItem item = CaptureHelper.CreateItemForWindow(hwnd);
        device = Direct3D11Helper.CreateDevice();
        capture = new BasicCapture(device, item);
        framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.Create(device, DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, 1, item.Size);
        session = framePool.CreateCaptureSession(item);
        session.StartCapture();

        using (frame = framePool.TryGetNextFrame())
        {
            var bmp = await SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(frame.Surface);
            StorageFolder pictureFolder = KnownFolders.CameraRoll;
            StorageFile file = await pictureFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);
                encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(bmp);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

If i put a breakpoint in line `using (frame = framePool.TryGetNextFrame())` the frame is populated and the file is saved normally by the code that follows.

If i just run the app then frame is null and an error occurs. I cant use await on the `framePool.TryGetNextFrame()`

I feel that this is a Frankenstein code as i am learning the new capturing paradigm. Any help how to make this code work?

Eventually i will need this code to work with a timer taking screenshots at a regular interval.

Answer (score 0):

`Direct3D11CaptureFramePool` has a [`FrameArrived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframepool.framearrived) event, which you could listen for before trying to get the frame:

```
var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
framePool.FrameArrived += (s, e) => cts.SetResult(null);

session.StartCapture();

await cts.Task;

// Frame should now be available
using (frame = framePool.TryGetNextFrame())
```